# Set a worksheet cells to return values of a function defined in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two files and its important the file type remains unchanged.
Firstly, Stack.xlsm
[image]
With only one row of data.
The following function takes the two datapoints and saves them into an array that is returned. So, the cells A5=StudentData(1), B5=StudentData(2)

```
Public Function StudentData(Index As Integer)
    Dim StudentID As Double
    Dim StudentScore As Double
    Dim IntA(1 To 2) As Double

    StudentID = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)
    StudentScore = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)
    
    IntA(1) = StudentID
    IntA(2) = StudentScore
    
    StudentData = IntA(Index)
    
End Function
```

Secondly, Test.xlsx.
I am trying to maintain this file as a .xlsx but somehow write data to it (This should be the result after running the desired sub):

[image]

I want to overwrite the cells in this sheet such that A1= "ID:" & StudentData(1), B1="Score:" &StudentData(2), ie calling the function defined in Stack.xlsm

I assume this will be achieved in Stack.xlsm, with something like:

```
Public Sub DataTransfer()
    Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").cell(A1) = "ID:" & StudentData(1)
    Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").cell(B1) = "Score:" & StudentData(2)
End Sub
```

The syntax is wrong but I hope it shows my intentions.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem with this code?  It's best to avoid use of ActiveSheet in your code if you can - reference a specific sheet instead.

Comment: What is the idea behind the `Index`? If it's supposed to represent the row, it should be used instead of `2` for the rows in the function. Its result should be `StudentData = IntA`. Also, in the method, instead of `.Cell(A1)` you should use `.Range("A1")`. You are doing this for one record. If you plan on using it in a loop, it might become too slow. Could you reveal the big picture or is that it (it's ok both ways)?

Comment: ‘’’index‘’’ is used to indicate the column. Which is why it’s used so a call with a different argument accesses the different values in the array. It’s purely for one record not multiple

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values

- When you do `Dim Student(1 To 2) As Double` (or in your function `Dim IntA(1 To 2) As Double`) you have already determined that you will be accessing the values by index i.e. `Student(1)` and `Student(2)`. There is no need (possibility) to use an index argument for that.
- If you're going to hard-code the row index, then your function signature will be

  ```
  Function StudentData(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Double()
  ```

  with one argument.
- If you're also going to hard-code the worksheet, then your function signature will be

  ```
  Function StudentData() As Double()
  ```

  without arguments.

**An Idea**

```vb
Function StudentData( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal RowIndex As Long) _
As Double()
    
    ' 'StudentID' and 'StudentScore' are beautiful variable names,
    ' but they don't serve much of a purpose.
    Dim StudentID As Double: StudentID = ws.Cells(RowIndex, "A").Value
    Dim StudentScore As Double: StudentScore = ws.Cells(RowIndex, "B").Value
    
    Dim Student(1 To 2) As Double
    Student(1) = StudentID
    Student(2) = StudentScore
    
    StudentData = Student
    
End Function

Sub DataTransfer()
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sRow As Long: sRow = 5
    Dim Student() As Double: Student = StudentData(sws, sRow)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = 1
    
    dws.Cells(dRow, "A").Value = "ID:" & Student(1)
    dws.Cells(dRow, "B").Value = "Score:" & Student(2)

End Sub
```

- Hopefully, you're just practicing to better understand ranges, arrays, functions, etc. because all these complications boil down to the following:

```vb
Sub DataTransferSolo()
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dws.Range("A1").Value = "ID:" & sws.Range("A5").Value
    dws.Range("B1").Value = "Score:" & sws.Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

**Finally**

- After finally understanding what you were doing, the problem with it is that you're retrieving both values (writing them from the worksheet to an array) to get only one value as the result of the function which is rather inefficient because you have to run it twice to get both values.
- Passing an array as the result, as shown in the above code, reads the data once (most importantly, accesses the worksheet once) and is the way to go. You can efficiently (quickly) access any value any number of times from the passed array in the calling procedure.